# Context 0x3abe010' is disconnected. Releasing the interfaces from the current context (context 0x3abdea0)

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm developing an application in C# which contains an Office Word component(in my case its `EDrawOfficeViewer`) in a tab control. Each tab which opens will contain a new word component. So when I try to open more than 10 tabs via a `for loop`, it throws this error without showing the line which caused it.

```
Context 0x3abe010' is disconnected. Releasing the interfaces from the current
context (context 0x3abdea0).This may cause corruption or data loss. 
To avoid this problem, please ensure that all contexts/apartments stay 
alive until the applicationis completely done with the RuntimeCallableWrapper
that represent COM components that liveinside them.
```

This is the code that will run in a `for loop` to opens my words:

```
_axEdOffice = new AxEDOffice();
SuperTabControlPanel panel = new SuperTabControlPanel();
SuperTabItem tabItem = new SuperTabItem
      {
         Text = dr["IDFish"].ToString(),
         Tag = dr["IDMiddleCategory"],
         AttachedControl = panel
      };
var item = stcWordTab.CreateTab(tabItem, panel, stcWordTab.Tabs.Count);

try
{
    panel.Controls.Add(_axEdOffice);
}
catch
{
     dr.Close();
     dr.Dispose();
     panel.Dispose();
     return;
}
_axEdOffice.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
stcWordTab.SelectedTab = item;
_axEdOffice.CreateNew("Word.Application");
_axEdOffice.WordDisableSaveHotKey(true);
string tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
FileStream file = new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
file.Close();
File.WriteAllText(tempFileName, temprtf, Encoding.UTF8);
_axEdOffice.WordInsertFile(tempFileName);
File.Delete(tempFileName);
```

I've searched through the net and found nothing useful. Does anyone know what causes this issue?

Comment: Hmm, this is an exception caused by threading.  No evidence for that whatsoever in the snippet.  No reason to start Word for every single tab btw.

Comment: @HansPassant But I can't move the current opened word component to the new tab, each time a new one is openning

Comment: "Move current word component to the new tab" makes little sense, Word is not a control.  But surely has something to do with the exception.  What on Earth are you really doing?

Comment: @HansPassant my application has a TreeView in which each root node includes some subnodes which is like a word file that can be opened in a new tab. Then when I'm trying to open all the subnodes of a rootnode, I get this error. Does it make sense?

Comment: "subnodes which is like a word file", give me a week to think about what that might mean.

Comment: @HansPassant TreeView nodes are read from a Sql database in which each record in table has a column containg the text. When user dblclicks on a node, a word component opens and the database text will set as its text

Comment: You should clearly state in your question that you are not using Microsoft Office but a third-party component.